# How to have multiple columns that consume 100% height using twitter bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have seen a number of similar questions, but have not found an answer for what I am looking for. Further information is as follows:

- I am using twitter bootstrap, so I would like a solution that is compatible with it
- The layout will look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3P85.png). Sorry I cannot embed the image because I need 10 pts first.
- [This](http://jsbin.com/ehizof) is as close as I have gotten so far. The problem is that I cannot get the sidebar to stop at the footer.
- I will need the main content to expand the same as the sidebar.
- The sidebar and Main Content are two different colors and vary in size. They must both extend to the footer
- Notice that the minimum height must be 100%
- The footer should move if the content grows too much (i.e. it would require scrolling to see it)
- I do no want to use JavaScript, but if it is required I wouldn't mind a solution with so long as it is progressively enhanced with the JS (I am also using jQuery).
- The page content is centered horizontally with a fixed width

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this might be, what you are looking for: [**two column layout**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/teresko/UG8Rk/show/) <sup>[source](http://jsfiddle.net/teresko/UG8Rk/)</sup>.

The main idea is to set `height: 100%` on both `<body>` and `<html>` and then make sure that the container also takes up all the height (via `min-height: 100%`). You might notice that code also contains workaround for IE6, because it was originally written, when fighting IE6 was just another day of work.

This was made by modifying a bit more complicated and more often used [holy grail layout](http://fiddle.jshell.net/teresko/EkTVv/show/) <sup>[source](http://jsfiddle.net/teresko/UG8Rk/)</sup>.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. I cannot up-vote until I have 15 reputation but I have indicated this was the correct answer.

Comment: How does this answer the question of "using twitter bootstrap" ?

Comment: Why would that have any impact ?

Answer (score 2):

Via css it may be possible but need some tricks.

You need to make both divs/columns very very tall by adding a padding-bottom: 1000px and then "trick the browser" into thinking they aren't that tall using margin-bottom: -1000px. It is better explained via example below.

http://jsfiddle.net/mediasoftpro/Ee7RS/

Hope this will be ok.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I have seen a few examples that use JavaScript, but strongly prefer not to require it; regardless, the example is much appreciated. Do you know if my requirements are possible without using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with **display:table;** to **Parent Div** and **display:table-cell;** to **Child Div** for achieving your results....

see the code :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  .container {
    background:red;
    width:600px;
    display:table;
  }

  .left {
    background:yellow;
    width:200px;
    display:table-cell;

  }


    .mid {
    background:blue;
    width:400px;
    display:table-cell;


  }

      .right {
    background:green;
    width:200px;
    display:table-cell;

  }



</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">shailender</div>
      <div class="mid">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
        fff</div>
      <div class="right">afdafaf</div>


  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Demo:-** http://jsbin.com/ebucoz/13/edit

**[Read More About Fluid Width Equal Height Columns with Examples](http://css-tricks.com/examples/FluidEqualHeightFauxColumns/#)**

Comment: Where is the use of Bootstrap? (and 'float' attribut)

Answer (score 0):

Hey i think you want this

**Css**

**

```
.wraper, .header, .footer{
width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:solid 2px red;
}
.header{
    height:100px;
    background:green;
    border-color:darkred;
}
.sidebar{
width:20%;
    background:yellow;
    float:left;
}
.content{
width:70%;
    background:pink;
    float:right;
}
.footer{
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
    border-color:black;
}
#container2 {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFA7A7;
clear: left;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
}
#container1 {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFF689;
float: left;
position: relative;
right: 75%;
width: 100%;
}
#sidebar {
float: left;
left:76%;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 20%;
text-align: justify;
}
#content {
    float: left;
    left: 81%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 72%;
}
```

**
**HTML**

```
    <div class="header">header bar </div>
    <div class="wraper">
        <div id="container2">
    <div id="container1">
        <div id="sidebar">
            This is dummy text here This is dummy text here This is dummy text here This is dummy text here This is dummy text here This is dummy text here This is dummy text
        </div>
        <div id="content">
           This is dummy text here This is dummy text here This is dummy
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
        <div class="footer">Footer bar</div>
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/Pgy75/2/

more about this [click here](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-2-column.htm) http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-2-column.htm

Answer (score 0):

The only real answer:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
```

```
<table border="1" height="100%" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="10%">
            left
        </td>
        <td>
            right
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```