# How to make two divs appear side by side using CSS not tables?

Tags: css, layout, html-table

How can I make two div appear side by side? I want the first div appear on left, and second to appear right beside that.

```
<div class="first">first</div>
<div class="second">second</div>
```

What I want:

> first   second

What I get:

> first
>    
>    second

Workaround with tables:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>first</td>
        <td>second</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How to make two divs behave like these two table cells?

Comment: Use `float` with left and right values.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10240515/727208) and explore the source. All of "answers" here will fail when left column has no content.

Comment: Remember if you are using CSS float property to align div side by side don't forget to clear float otherwise parent elements will be collapsed. Check this page to learn perfect alignment of div tag using float property - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-alignment.php

Comment: This question is not a genuine issue, instead it is the result of not learning the basics of HTML or CSS. Also, there are multiple duplicate questions on SO that answer this question perfectly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to add float left to your first div and it will work!

Comment: He needs to float **both**

Comment: add float to both divs

Comment: floating the "first" div defined in the markup is enough.

Comment: @andrewb I commented on your answer already

Answer (score 7):

you can use

```
 float:left
```

[DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/SxDWn/)

Comment: So far the correct answer

Answer (score 6):

basically there are 2 techniques.

1. using `float`. assign a floating value (`left` | `right`) to your elements, and they will span one after each other like inline elements based on available space.
   *Downsize*: floating breaks the normal flow of the page, so you'll have to use [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) methods to make the parent container long as his content. (actually not so bad)
2. using `inline-block`. assign `display:inline-block` to your block elements to make them span one after each other like 'inline' elements based on available space.
   *Downsize:* each 'new-line' in the markup is treated like a white-space with inline-block elements, causing gapes between elements in the view. and also, assigning 'inline-block' to 'inline-block' elements isn't supported in IE7, so you'll have to use methods to [overcome the gap](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/), and [IE7 Hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

I actually prefer the `inline-block` method.

Comment: IIRC, the `inline-block` in IE7 will be actually rendered as `inline`, which can (and usually - will) cause additional problems. Anyway, IE7 in most projects is not supported an the 3px gap has [known solutions](http://haslayout.net/css/3px-Gap-Bug-aka-Text-Jog-Bug).

Comment: I already linked to good articles about those problems and how to address them.

Answer (score 4):

simple, Use `float:left;` to the divs css,

```
<div style="float:left" > </div>
<div style="float:left" > </div>
```

and [CSS Floats 101](http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101), best place to make an understandind of it, very helpful.

Comment: The reason to float the 2nd div is so it doesn't necessarily extend to the right margin. Right?

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone The question is to make two div appear side by side, so to make the second div right next to the first div.

Answer (score 1):

Many ways. You could float the "first"/leftmost div like in this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/2ENMK/

CSS:

```
div.left
{
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

div.lefthugger
{
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: [Fails](http://jsfiddle.net/2ENMK/1/) and see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2ENMK/2/)